# FCGIWrapper not picking up php.ini file path

Tags: php, fastcgi, php5, php.ini

I'm using Fast CGI with PHP, and it runs great except I just noticed it's not picking up the php ini path. It seems not to pick up the -c argument at all and says no configuration file is loaded when I do phpinfo()

I'm using:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
FCGIWrapper '/usr/bin/php-cgi -c /path/to/php.ini' .php
```

Oddly running from the command line it does work.

```
[tim@localhost ~] $ /usr/bin/php-cgi -c /path/to/php.ini -i | grep Loaded\ Configuration\ File
<tr><td class="e">Loaded Configuration File </td><td class="v">/path/to/php.ini </td></tr>
```

Further details
PHP 5.2.10 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 20 2009 18:09:05)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out it this was a file permissions issue.

My ini directory was owned root:apache and changing to root:root suddenly got the config picked up.

No errors were raised informing me of the bad permissions though